# How can I dock a boat without breaking it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to construct a useable dock in Minecraft.  Boats should be able to land safely without breaking, then be useable at a later time with little fuss.  Ideally, monsters should also not be able to push the boats off the dock.

How can I construct such a dock in Minecraft?

Comment: Note that [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10561/is-there-any-way-to-reuse-a-boat) has a number of answers that suggest certain dock types, but they don't meet my criteria - slowsand makes entering a docked boat difficult, and the other dock pictured has a very small contained space that could be dangerous to docking boaters.

Comment: [Related](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/137822/is-it-normal-for-a-boat-to-break-after-like-5-blocks-travel-distance)

Comment: Try using wool. In earlier versions I remember it used to help with this issue.

Comment: I imagine soul sand, a tripwire and a retracting piston to get the boat back in the water can work. A cactus, hopper and dispenser might also work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two half-steps placed at the lower half of the water level surrounded by other blocks seems to work well.

H = Half step, B = Block, W = Water

```
[B][B][B][B]    
[B][H][H][B]
[B][W][W][B]
[B][W][W][B]
```

If you want to keep mobs from pushing the boat out, you could include pistons at the open end.

Comment: Half blocks are good, but I'd use more of them to create a wider landing base, and not surround them with normal blocks, making it easier to land from any angle at high speed.

Comment: Good point. That would totally get you kicked out of a real life harbor though! ;)